# Params and Variables must be at the top of a template?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I'd thought that params and variables must be at the top of a template.. yet i can successfully compile this code:

```
   <xsl:template name="WriteOptions">
      <xsl:param name="input"/>
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="true()">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:param name="head" select="substring-before($input, ',')"/>
         <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($input, ',')"/>
         <option value="{$head}"><xsl:value-of select="$head"/></option>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

So i was wondering what's the catch

Comment: Which xslt processor are you using? That definitely shouldn't work.

Comment: It's a [static error](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTSE0010) definitely.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer which completes something lacking in the rest of the other answers -- explanation of the different rules governing an `xsl:variable`.

Comment: i'm using notepad to save the files, and opening them with safari web browser.

Comment: @Flynn1179 i'm using notepad to save the files, and opening them with safari web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only an `xsl:param` within an `xsl:template` must be a child of the `xsl:template` instruction.

**There is no such requirement for an `xsl:variable`** -- the W3C XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 specifications allow them to appear at any depth in the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: do you mean a direct child? Btw must the `xsl:param` be the first child of the `xsl:template` for it to be considered valid?

Comment: @Pacerier: In XPath a child is only direct. "Indirect child" is called a descendant. The`<xsl:param>` has to be either global (not within any template), or if it is in a template it must be one of a sequence of `<xsl:param>` elements and this sequence should not have any preceding-sibling node that is not itself an `<xsl:param>`.

Comment: ok just to make sure.. i can never have a mistake with `xsl:variable` since it is free to appear anywhere in the document right?

Comment: why do we even need to use params if that's the  case.. `xsl:variable`s are so much more flexible

Comment: @Pacerier: Params are necessary, well ... to specify parameters to be passed to templates or to the transformation (in case of global params). Global params cannot be passed to an `xsl:variable`. Also, you are right that it is possible to use a global variable instead of passing a param, howeverin many cases this is not sufficient, because any `xsl:variable` is immutable and you may want to pass as a parameter a value that was dynamically generated inside another template. Also using global variables (static variables) is a bad practice in any programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-syntax-summary), you can write `<xsl:param>` as a child of `<xsl:template>` and `<xsl:stylesheet>` (or `<xsl:transform>`, which is the alternative top level element in XSLT).

If your stylesheet compiles, then your XSLT processor behaves non-standard.

Comment: Agreed. I've come across processors that fail to detect this error: Xalan perhaps?

Comment: @Michael: I suppose the affected processor treats an out-of-place `param` like a `variable`. Not a nice feature, IMHO.